# How do I align an element in lightning-record-edit-form?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have a field on the form and I want to align the checkbox and the name on the same line. How do I do this? By default, it is located like this:

[image]

```
    <template>
    <div if:true={showStepOne}>
        <div role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h1 class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Work Type</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiNameWorkType} onsuccess={handleSuccessOne}>
                        <lightning-messages>
                        </lightning-messages>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={NAME_WORK_TYPE}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={DESCRIPTION_WORK_TYPE}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={ESTIMATED_DURATION_WORK_TYPE}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={DURATION_TYPE_WORK_TYPE}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name={AUTO_CREATE_APPT} type="checkbox" checked>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                            <lightning-button
                                class="slds-float_right"
                                variant="brand"
                                type="submit"
                                label="Next">
                            </lightning-button>
                    </lightning-record-edit-form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

After adding `variant= "label-inline"` to the field, the layout still didn't work the way I needed it to. Can this be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by properly applying selectors in a css file, thus changing the positioning, however, you can also use [lightning-layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout) to your form items to place them differently.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `variant="label-inline"` to the `lightning-input-field` to get the field label aligned to the left side. This value defaults to standard, which displays the label above the field.

[lightning-input documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but after adding variant= "label-inline", the layout still didn't work the way I needed it. Added a screenshot to the question description. Can this be changed?

Comment: You can remove the standard label through the 'variant="label-hidden"' then add the label text separately. But you will loose the lable click functionality and you will have to figure a way out.